# Dictionary Appending in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, append

Right now, data and filenameVariable are printing the final row when I need all rows. I tried .append but that didn't work. What else could I use?

Here is the data I'm working with:

```
    someCSVfile.csv|cust_no,0|streetaddr,1|city,2|state,3|zip,4|phone_home,5|firstname,6|lastname,7|status,9|
    someCSVfile1.csv|cust_no,0|streetaddr,1|city,2|state,3|zip,4|phone_home,5|firstname,6|lastname,7|status,9|
```

And here's the code so far:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('match_log.txt','rb'), dialect='excel', delimiter='|')

data = {}

for row in reader:
  filenameVariable = row[0] 
  data = dict(item.split(',') for item in row[1:])

print data
print filenameVariable

#right now its taking the final row. I need all rows
```

Comment: What output data structure are you looking for? A list of dictionaries? A dictionary of dictionaries (keyed on what)? At the moment, you create a new dictionary on each iteration, but don't do anything with it.

Comment: **how** did `.append()` not work? You are replacing `data` with a new dictionary every loop iteration here; have you tried creating a list and appending to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are overwriting `data` each line in the CSV. Instead, all you need to do is have the `row[0]` as a key in the `data` dict:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('match_log.txt','rb'), dialect='excel', delimiter='|')

filenameVariable = []
data = {}

for row in reader:
  filenameVariable.append(row[0])
  data[row[0]] = dict(item.split(',') for item in row[1:])

print data
print filenameVariable
```

Comment: This works! But what if I didn't want row[0] as my key in the data dict and I wanted the data dictionary to stand alone. Should i make the data variable into a list?

Comment: Yes you could do that and have a list of independent `dict` objects.